# Wiped and Reformatted external hard drive says it is completely full and windows cannot access it

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, ntfs, formatting, wipe

I had a 1TB external HDD that developed an unresponsive folder. I used the errors checking tool on the properties tool tab, and that repaired the folder. I then moved the data off to a replacement disk. Then I used a built-in windows disk management/format to completely erase everything on the disk because there was one file there I wanted to erase securely.

I selected NTFS... now the disk properties say it is 100% full, and windows cannot access the disk beyond displaying the properties. I had planned to make the disk blank, therefore empty... Not sure what went wrong. Any advice on how to fix it? I'm alright with just tossing it because it did develop that error... this is a 2yo Seagate with fairly heavy read/write usage and is making a nice coaster.

---

**EDIT**: It was a seagate 'nominal 1TB' disk, so slightly smaller (931GB) in usable space.

The unresponsive folder on the disk was made usable again simply by using the windows error checking tool on the tools tab of the disk properties screen. That fixed the problem quickly. I successfully accessed the folder and copied alllll the data onto a new HDD.

Then I wanted to erase allllll the data off the old HDD. How I broke the old HDD is this: I went to windows 10 disk management/action/all tasks/format/file system/ntfs, then I unchecked "perform a quick format" then committed to the action. Obvs I am not a superuser! ;)

Now when I go to the properties of the disk it says 100% of the space is used, and if I try to explore the disk, windows just does nothing, cannot "read" any of the full emptiness of this disk. I could upload a video of me trying to open it? Thank you again everyone.

Comment: Are you attempting to "securely erase" files on an HDD with the Windows disk management tool? Selecting delete partition there will probably just erase the partition table and not the data on the disk. Now regarding your question have you checked the partition size of the partition, does it indeed show 1TB? "Unresponsive Folder" - Did you take a look at the HDD S.M.A.R.T. data to check for a hardware fault, using a tool like Crystal Disk Info?

Comment: Use diskpart command "clean" on the drive, then format in disk management.

Comment: Can we see SMART report/screenshot CrystalDisk for example)?